# Retrieve Decimal Precision from configuration table and format while displaying - SSRS

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating one SSRS report.Now i am formatting decimal data using Number property of textbox.But there is requirement where number of decimal precision can be read form a config table(SQL Server) and it should be used for formatting decimal data.I am new to SSRS reports.How can i achieve this is in SSRS. Can anyone explain in detail on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an expression and use `FormatNumber` (and set the formatting in the text box to default):

```
=FormatNumber(Fields!myValueCol.Value,Fields!dec.Value)
```

EDIT: if the config value is in a different dataset, use a `Lookup`:

```
=FormatNumber(Fields!myValueCol.Value,Lookup( 12, Fields!ConfigID.Value, Fields!DecimalPrecision.Value, "DataSet_configdata")  )
```

Comment: Assume there is sql table called "configdata" and it has column "DecimalPrecision" .How to retrieve Fields!dec.Value ? throught different dataset ?

Comment: What does "12" indicates ?.Based on requirement,precision is constant for entire report even if it have different datasets

Comment: It's just a random id.  This is the value that is looked up in ConfigID

Comment: Yes..It is working..But is any way like this precision value can be fetched only once and stored it somewhere on a constant and it can be used in expression instead of lookup..Otherewise lookup function need to be applied each and every expression where we have to format the data

Comment: Create a hidden parameter and put a default value (from the 2nd dataset) with your precision. No need for lookup then.

Comment: Before confirming the answer..one doubt...whether FormatNumber will convert it to a string ?? Does it cause any issue on exported excel.I Want to maintain it as decimal tself n the exported excel